# Single ItemsSource binding data grid combobox

Tags: c#, wpf

How to set single ItemsSource to combobox **based on some condition** in wpf datagrid

xaml code

```
  <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Margin="67,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="170" Width="388">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Raw Materials" Width="*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedRawMaterials.Display}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Display" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedRawMaterials}" SelectedValuePath="Value" ItemsSource="{Binding RMColloction}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Raw Materials" Width="*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedSize.Display}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Display" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedSize}" SelectedValuePath="Value" ItemsSource="{Binding SizeColloction}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

</Grid>
```

MVVM Models

```
   public class RawMaterials
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Display { get; set; }
}

public class Size
{
    public int RMId { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Display { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public Item()
    {
        RMColloction = new List<RawMaterials>();
        RMColloction.Add(new RawMaterials() { Display = "RM1", Value = 1 });
        RMColloction.Add(new RawMaterials() { Display = "RM2", Value = 2 });
        RMColloction.Add(new RawMaterials() { Display = "RM3", Value = 3 });
        RMColloction.Add(new RawMaterials() { Display = "RM4", Value = 4 });
        RMColloction.Add(new RawMaterials() { Display = "RM5", Value = 5 });
        RMColloction.Add(new RawMaterials() { Display = "RM6", Value = 6 });
        SizeColloction = new List<Size>();
        SizeColloction.Add(new Size() { Display = "A", Value = 1, RMId = 1 });
        SizeColloction.Add(new Size() { Display = "B", Value = 2, RMId = 2 });
        SizeColloction.Add(new Size() { Display = "C", Value = 3, RMId = 2 });
        SizeColloction.Add(new Size() { Display = "D", Value = 4, RMId = 1 });
        SizeColloction.Add(new Size() { Display = "E", Value = 5, RMId = 2 });
        SizeColloction.Add(new Size() { Display = "F", Value = 6, RMId = 1 });
    }
    public List<RawMaterials> RMColloction { get; set; }
    public List<Size> SizeColloction { get; set; }

    public RawMaterials SelectedRawMaterials { get; set; }
    public Size SelectedSize { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel

```
 public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

}
```

Here I need SizeColloction ComboBox fill based on RawMaterialsColloction RMId..
Is It possible to get  second combo Items based on first combo selected value with same referance?

Comment: what have you tried? what code do you have so far? what condition? what combo box??? anything?????

Comment: Please give some more details about exactly what you are trying to do and what you've done that isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use ICollectionView. Refer below code.

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Margin="67,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="170" Width="388">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Raw Materials" Width="*" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedRawMaterials.Display,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Display" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedRawMaterials,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedValuePath="Value" ItemsSource="{Binding RMColloction}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Raw Materials" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedSize.Display}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Display" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedSize}" SelectedValuePath="Value" ItemsSource="{Binding SizeFiltered}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

 public class Item:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ICollectionView SizeFiltered { get; set; }
    public Item()
    {
        RMColloction = new ObservableCollection<RawMaterials>();
        RMColloction.Add(new RawMaterials() { Display = "RM1", Value = 1 });
        RMColloction.Add(new RawMaterials() { Display = "RM2", Value = 2 });
        RMColloction.Add(new RawMaterials() { Display = "RM3", Value = 3 });
        RMColloction.Add(new RawMaterials() { Display = "RM4", Value = 4 });
        RMColloction.Add(new RawMaterials() { Display = "RM5", Value = 5 });
        RMColloction.Add(new RawMaterials() { Display = "RM6", Value = 6 });
        SizeColloction = new ObservableCollection<Size>();
        SizeColloction.Add(new Size() { Display = "A", Value = 1, RMId = 1 });
        SizeColloction.Add(new Size() { Display = "B", Value = 2, RMId = 2 });
        SizeColloction.Add(new Size() { Display = "C", Value = 3, RMId = 2 });
        SizeColloction.Add(new Size() { Display = "D", Value = 4, RMId = 1 });
        SizeColloction.Add(new Size() { Display = "E", Value = 5, RMId = 2 });
        SizeColloction.Add(new Size() { Display = "F", Value = 6, RMId = 1 });

        SizeFiltered = new CollectionViewSource { Source = SizeColloction }.View;
        SizeFiltered.Filter = RmFilter;
    }

    private bool RmFilter(object item)
    {
        bool filter=false;
        if (SelectedRawMaterials != null)
        {
            if ((((Size)item).RMId == SelectedRawMaterials.Value))
                filter= true;
            else
                filter= false;
        }
        return filter;
    }
    public ObservableCollection<RawMaterials> RMColloction { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Size> SizeColloction { get; set; }       

    private RawMaterials selectedRawMaterials;

    public RawMaterials SelectedRawMaterials
    {
        get { return selectedRawMaterials; }
        set 
        { 
            selectedRawMaterials = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedRawMaterials");
            SizeFiltered.Refresh();
        }
    }   

    public Size SelectedSize { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```